# Is there a pure LaTeX or TeX package for chart drawing?

Tags: graphs, datatool

We are creating an easy-to-use LaTeX template for our institution. I'd like to have a pure LaTeX way to create simple bar graphs and pie charts. Does anything exist? I can certainly throw the students at matplotlib or gnuplot, but it would be nice to have something simpler.

Comment: Well, there is [TikZ/PGF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PGF/TikZ) which is a pure LaTeX way to create basically any form of diagram. However, LaTeX beginners would benefit from a macro wrapper where they just can feed there values and styles in. No idea if such a macro for bar and pie charts already exists.

Comment: I wouldn't say `TikZ/PGF` is *simpler* than matplotlib. However, it produced much nicer results. With `matplotlib`, I always have issues when I want larger fonts; I usually reduce the figure-size while keeping font-sizes, but then labels fall outside the figure. Calculating bounding-boxes is one of the strengths of `LaTeX`, so I would recommend `pgfplots`, not because it's simpler, but because it produces nicer results, particularly when larger fonts are needed (like in presentations).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The usual answer here is the [`pgfplots`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) package, which is based on TikZ. Note that it does not do pie charts, as these are considered misleading by many people. (There is some discussion of this issue in the TikZ manual.)

(Note: As mathematicians use 'graphs' for something entirely different, the usual way to refer to data display in a graphical form is as a 'plot'. You'll find a number of plot-related questions on the site.)

Comment: Thanks. I also do not like pie charts (see http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/08-21-07.pdf), but people demand them. Thanks for the pointer to pgfplots. I was not aware of it. It's pretty amazing.

Comment: Re: Pie charts; I think that the "misleading"-part in the pgfmanual was in relation to "3d" piecharts, not "flat" piecharts.

Comment: What is a good alternative to a pie chart, which can represent this kind of data, such as percentages?

Comment: @Village The problem with pie charts is actually comparing the sizes is hard, so people tend to put the numbers on. At that point, a table is a better choice.

Comment: @Village: another good alternative is a bar chart. I remember finding a nice comparison but I can't seem to remember where.

Comment: @Village: found it: http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/08-21-07.pdf

Answer (score 6):

Pure (La)TeX charts are possible in a variety of ways. Most notable are the options offered by [TikZ/PGF](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and [PStricks](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/). See the respective documentations for ample examples on the functionality and use.

Although PStricks is predominantly Postscript orientated, it can be used in PDF environments as well by using the [`auto-pst-pdf`](http://ctan.org/pkg/auto-pst-pdf) wrapper.

Using PStricks, the [`pst-bar` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-bar) provides an interface for bar charts. View the [PStricks bar chart gallery](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Charts/chart#bar0) for more on the possibilities. The [PStricks pie chart gallery](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Charts/chart#pie0) also has some neat examples of pie charts. PStricks also has [`pst-plot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-plot) from plotting charts from external files (or not). [`pst-2dplot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-2dplot) provides an interface for a variety of 2D plots (see the [2D gallery page](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-plot/examples)), while [`pst-3dplot`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pst-3dplot) does the same for surfaces and other 3D charts (see the [3D gallery page](http://www.tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-plot/3D/examples)).

Answer (score 2):

An answer depends, in part, on what you mean by "pure" LaTeX. [MetaPost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MetaPost), as this page mentions, is included in the TeXLive distribution and there is extensive documentation on Piecharts in MetaPost that can be downloaded [here](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/metapost/contrib/macros/piechartmp/piechartmp.pdf). Likewise, there is a Python package for Latex [here](http://www.texample.net/weblog/2008/oct/24/embedding-python-latex/) so you can run LaTeX, jump into Python, create your graphs and jump back. There is a sagetex package as well (for Sage) and one for gnuplot. With respect to PSTricks, check the [pstricks-add](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pstricks-add) package for nice piecharts and the [pst-func](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pst-func) for barcharts. Note that a previous post has `pst-bar` as well.

Answer (score 2):

And do not forget about [datatool](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/datatool) bundle!  Its user interface is not the easiest to use (and it is also quite verbose), but you can wrap it into a few macros of your own and then it might be very useful.