# What are some good graphing libraries/programs for embedding in LaTeX

Tags: diagrams, graphs

The de-facto plotting program for LaTeX is, AFAIA, [gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/).

Is there such a program for drawing graphs/diagrams? I am aware of [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/) and at first glance it appears very useful, but it is missing certain basic features such as specifying multiple rank orders (arrange left to right, top to bottom... [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014092/does-the-dot-directed-graph-allow-for-subgraphs-with-a-different-rankdir)) or subscripts/superscripts. It apparently [allows for html formatting](https://mailman.research.att.com/pipermail/graphviz-interest/2007q2/004502.html) which in theory provides for subscripts/superscripts, but it does not seem to work. [dot2tex](http://www.fauskes.net/code/dot2tex/) attempts to make graphviz more LaTeX friendly, but the generated graphs are not as sharp, C style comments, which are valid in graphviz files, appear to conflict with LaTeX files, even when included as a `doc` file, and I, personally, can't figure out how to embed the graph as a figure as opposed to a dangling graph.

Is there a way to address some of these shortcomings:

- no sub/superscripts
- no figures
- no comments

If not, is there a way to output the file to a more LaTeX friendly format, much like gnuplot does with its [latex format](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tips_and_Tricks#Graphs_with_gnuplot), such that I can use LaTeX's math mode?

**EDIT** here are two pictures to better describe what I mean by graphs and/or diagrams

[image: Diagram 1]

[image: Diagram 2]

Comment: Is something like [`sagetex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/sagetex) of interest? I must admit, I'm not *exactly* sure what you're after, since "graphs" and "diagrams" are very general.

Comment: What about proposals in [Is there a pure LaTeX or TeX package for chart drawing?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31156/is-there-a-pure-latex-or-tex-package-for-chart-drawing)

Comment: @Werner I'll include some pictures to clarify

Comment: Who answers the obvious? (TikZ)

Comment: Too lazy to write an answer, so I'll just add two links to TeXample: http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/block-diagrams/ and http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/tag/diagrams/

Comment: @TorbjørnT. technically Patrick is lazier than you since he didn't even post a link

Comment: @PatrickGundlach when you two have some free time, could you possibly, in the form of an answer, explain why those are better alternatives

Comment: I don't know very much about TikZ, I even ignore everything related to this on tex.sx. But usually I hear people writing "just do this with TikZ".

Comment: Asymptote is a good alternative of MetaPost.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As the commenters mentioned, TikZ can do these graphics and use the full power of LaTeX. A main advantage is that, unlike pstricks, the package works for all output drivers, most notably PS and PDF. Everything will compile with just one (or two) `latex`/`pdflatex` run(s), no extra setup required. Not to mention the plethora of features described in the excellent 700+ pages [manual](http://mirror.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/generic/pgf/pgfmanual.pdf) (with tutorial).

While we're at it, try R and its [TikZ device](https://github.com/Sharpie/RTikZDevice) for plotting.

Comment: That manual should be slapped in the face of every first year computer scientist until they adopt its style entirely! I have never seen a tutorial that great. Not on w3schools, not on wikipedia, not even in strategy guides. +1,000,000

Answer (score 3):

The best tool is John Hobby's MetaPost, that can use a TeX engine (with whatever format: plain, LaTeX, and so on) [or by the way a troff engine too...] for the layout of "labels", and propose all the features of a programming/scripting language METAFONT like with a PostScript output. I use this for almost all my drawings; and to create easily legends and layout for maps---MetaPost can be considered as a PostScript scripting language too; so really handy to program the customization of maps.

MetaPost is a fantastic tool. To be found in, I think, all the TeX distributions---and of course: kerTeX.

The caveat is that to "see" the result, one needs a PostScript interpreter---while with METAFONT, you have also a rasterizer. (I even think that it could be useful in the future, for kerTeX, whether to develop a "MostScript", that is a PostScript limited interpreter able to render MetaPost figures; or to add back the rasterizing capabilities of METAFONT in MetaPost to be free from the need of a PostScript interpreter (software or "hardware" [printer]).

Comment: Asymptote has C++-like syntax to define points by equations (like MetaPost).

Answer (score 2):

[diagrams](https://diagrams.github.io/) is a domain-specific language for creating vector graphics using [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/). It has several backends that allow for direct [embedding into LaTeX files](https://diagrams.github.io/doc/latex.html). As an example, take a look at the diagrams in [Brent Yorgey's PhD thesis](https://github.com/byorgey/thesis), that are all done with this library (you can see the examples in the [pdf](https://github.com/byorgey/thesis/blob/master/Yorgey-thesis-final-2014-11-14.pdf)... jump to the diagrams linked in the List of Figures (the sources are available in the repository)).

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to the `tikz` libraries available, there are numerous [`pstricks`](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi/) [examples](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=examples), for [2D](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery/Gallery) and [3D](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=Examples/Gallery3D/Gallery3D) representations.

Since the images you present looks like flowcharts, see the [flowchart gallery](http://tug.org/PSTricks/main.cgi?file=pst-node/psmatrix/psmatrix#flowchart).